# npm not working . npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL . How to solve?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, proxy, npx

The following error is shown when  creating a react app using

```
npx create-react-app appname
```

```
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL 
npm ERR! Invalid URL  
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-04T06_24_41_949Z-debug-0.log.
```

How can I solve this? And also I am unable to install new libraries. But the versions of node.js and npm are still shown. And also I can run my previous projects with the command npm start.

I had tried out many ways like reinstalling node.js, running commands like

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app,
npm install -g create-react-app,
npm init,
npm install create-react-app,
npx create-react-app myapp,
```

Also I had tried cleaning the cache using

```
npm cache clean --force
```

But everything failed to solve this error. Please anyone help me.

The following is the log file

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

1 info using npm@9.6.7

2 info using node@v18.17.1

3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms

4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms

5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms

6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms

7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms

8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms

9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\LENOVO\OneDrive\Desktop\react\.npmrc Completed in 0ms

10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms

11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\LENOVO\.npmrc Completed in 1ms

12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms

13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms

14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms

15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms

16 timing config:load Completed in 11ms

17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms

18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms

19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms

20 verbose title npm exec create-react-app test

21 verbose argv "exec" "--" "create-react-app" "test"

22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms

23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms

24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms

25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-05T14_10_04_834Z-

26 verbose logfile C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-05T14_10_04_834Z-debug-0.log

27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 8ms

28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms

29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms

30 timing npm:load Completed in 27ms

31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms

32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files

33 silly logfile done cleaning log files

34 timing command:exec Completed in 28ms

35 verbose stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL

35 verbose stack     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)

35 verbose stack     at new URL (node:internal/url:611:13)

35 verbose stack     at getProxyUri (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:160:53)

35 verbose stack     at getAgent (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:21:17)

35 verbose stack     at remoteFetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\remote.js:31:17)

35 verbose stack     at cacheFetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\cache\index.js:16:28)

35 verbose stack     at async fetch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\fetch.js:98:7)

35 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:87:19)

35 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:118:23)

35 verbose stack     at async getManifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:30:22)

36 verbose cwd C:\Users\LENOVO\OneDrive\Desktop\react

37 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621

38 verbose node v18.17.1

39 verbose npm  v9.6.7

40 error code ERR_INVALID_URL

41 error Invalid URL

42 verbose exit 1

43 timing npm Completed in 453ms

44 verbose code 1

45 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-05T14_10_04_834Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Could you post the error log here, you could get the log file at `C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-04T06_24_41_949Z-debug-0.log`

Comment: I have now attached the log file above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem with the proxy settings. Check out this article: https://weekendprojects.dev/posts/how-to-fix-npm-err_invalid_url/#what-does-err_invalid_url-mean